# Sending SMS via adb

Tags: adb

I have used keyevent 66 to click on send, i can see that keyevent is working right its clicking on the desired button but still SMS not sent

I am using following code still my message is not sent on desired number.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:$no --es sms_body SMS_BODY_GOES_HERE --ez exit_on_sent true

adb shell input keyevent 22

adb shell input keyevent 66
```

I can see enter has been pressed but don't know why sms is not sent.

Comment: Do you enter these commands manually or in a script? If it is the latter your timing may be too fast.

Comment: I have used these commands manually as well as using script. In both cases its not working. Also I have used delay before performing every action

Comment: Your question has already been answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580199/sending-a-sms-on-android-through-adb)